# text elements not visible when appended from function

Tags: d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I want to add text to my d3 visualization using a function in append() function. But even the resulting DOM is exactly as when adding text static (passing the text directly to append()) it is not visible on the svg canvas.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", 800);
svg.attr("height", 600);

svg.selectAll("g.m1").data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "m1")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", function(d) {
    return d + ".0em"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Hello world directly: " + d;
  });

svg.selectAll("g.m2").data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "m2")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,150)")
  .append(function(d) {
    var t = d3.create("text");
    t.attr("dy", d + ".0em")
      .text("Hello world via function: " + d);
    return t.node();
  });
```

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

text {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In output I only see the text in the "m1" texts and not the "m2" texts. Even the output HTML is exactly the same:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdI0K.jpg

Comment: why do you use this `.append(function(d){})` construction?

Comment: In the example it is not needed, however, in my real world scenario it is to calculate and wrap the text in several lines. For that I need the data object provided by using the function

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a disconnected SVG element, you must supply a namespace i.e. svg:text rather than just text.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", 800);
svg.attr("height", 600);

svg.selectAll("g.m1").data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "m1")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)")
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", function(d) {
    return d + ".0em"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "Hello world directly: " + d;
  });

svg.selectAll("g.m2").data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "m2")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,150)")
  .append(function(d) {
    var t = d3.create("svg:text");
    t.attr("dy", d + ".0em")
      .text("Hello world via function: " + d);
    return t.node();
  });
```

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

text {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! Any reference where I should have found it myself? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md and https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#namespaces not sure that makes it explicit though.